# Read-only: No corresponding table column in Laravel PHP artisan

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, orm, laravel-artisan

I'm developing a web using Laravel 9. I used the command `sail php make:migration add_bought_to_products_table` to add a boolean column called "bought" in a products table. When trying to modify the value using Eloquent helpers `(Product::where('id', $product->id)->update(array('bought'=>true))` **the value is not updated in the database**. When looking at it, I se that the new field "bought" created by the migration is marked as **Read-only: No corresponding table column**.

The migration code is the following:

```
    <?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->boolean('bought');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn('bought');
        });
    }
};
```

Here a screenshot of the database:

[image]

I have already tried to clean the cache and rebuild many times the database doing a rollback and migrating again. The curious thing is that I previously added the field "visibility" which works perfectly **with the exact same code and steps** as the field that is giving the problem.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After breaking my head a lot, I solved it by simply doing a clean restart of the docker containers. It seems that the issue had nothing to do with Laravel but with Docker!

For anyone experiencing similar issues: **make sure to end Docker and all containers and do a clean restart.**

Answer (score 1):

I simply restarted my database tool and it was gone.